# Understanding CQRS and EventSourcing

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I read several blogs and watched video about usefulness of CQRS and ES. I am left with implementation confusion.

CQRS: when use separate table, one for "Write, Update and delete" and other for Read operation. So then how the data sync from write table to read table. Do we required to use cron job to sync data to read only table from write table or any other available options ?

Event Sourcing: Do we store only all Immutable sequential operation as record for each update happened upon once created in one storage. Or do we also store mutable record I mean the same record is updated in another storage

And Please explain RDBMS, NoSQL and Messaging to be used and where they fit into it

Answer (score 1):

> when use separate table, one for "Write, Update and delete" and other for Read operation. So then how the data sync from write table to read table.

You design an asynchronous process that understands how to transform the data from its "write" representation to its "read" representation, and you design a scheduler to decide when that asynchronous process runs.

Part of the point is that it's just plumbing, and you can choose whatever plumbing you want that satisfies your operational needs.

> Event Sourcing

On the happy path, each "event stream" is a append only sequence of immutable events.  In the case where you are enforcing a domain invariant over the contents of the stream, you'll normally have a "first writer wins" conflict policy.

But "the" stream is the authoritative copy of the events.  There may also be non-authoritative copies (for instance, events published to a message bus).  They are typically all immutable.

In some domains, where you have to worry about privacy and "the right to be forgotten", you may need affordances that allow you to remove information from a previously stored event.  Depending on your design choices, you may need mutable events there.

> RDBMS

For many sorts of queries, especially those which span multiple event streams, being able to describe the desired results in terms of relations makes the programming task much easier.  So a common design is to have asynchronous process that read information from the event streams and update the RDBMS.  The usual derived benefit is that you get low latency queries (but the data returned by those queries may be stale).

RDBMS can also be used as the core of the design of the event store / message store itself.  Events are common written as blob data, with interesting metadata exposed as additional columns.  The message store used by eventide-project is based on postgresql.

> NoSQL

Again, can potentially be used as your cache of readable views, or as your message store, depending on your needs.   Event Store would be an example of a NoSQL message store.

> Messaging

Messaging is a pattern for temporal decoupling; the ability to store/retrieve messages in a stable central area affords the ability to shut down a message producer without blocking the message consumer, and vice versa.  Message stores also afford some abstraction - the producer of a message doesn't necessarily know all of the consumers, and the consumer doesn't necessarily know all of the producers.

> My Question is about Event Sourcing. Do we required only immutable sequence events to be stored and where to be stored ?

In event sourcing, the authoritative representation of the state is the sequence of events - your durable copy of that event sequence is the book of truth.

As for where they go?  Well, that is going to depend on your architecture and storage choices.  You could manage files on disk yourself, you could write them in to your own RDBMS; you could use an RDBMS designed by somebody else, you could use a NoSQL document store, you could use a dedicated message store.

There could be multiple stores -- for instance, in a micro service architecture, the service that accepts orders might be different from the service that tracks order fulfillment, and they could each be writing events into different storage appliances.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation My Question is about Event Sourcing. Do we required only immutable sequence events to be stored and where to be stored ? Or along with this we required to save only the updated state(i.e, For example if current state was 'Order created' then same record updated to 'order delivered') also in separate storage and if yes where to be stored ?